# How To Mix two bytes[] audio Chunk with NAudio to retrieve one mixed byte[]

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I’m new with NAudio and I need to achieve following:

I have a sip Event that return to me an uint rtp buffer that I convert in `byte[]` Chunk with following code:

```
rtpChunk = new byte[buflen];
Marshal.Copy(buf, rtpChunk, 0, buflen);
```

I have one other `bytes[]` chunk of background music.

```
var backChunk = new byte[buflen];
Array.Copy(bot.BackgroundBuffer, bot.BackgroundBufferIndex, backChunk, 0, buflen);
```

I need to mix together and retrieve the mixed chunk in `byte[]` and send back as uint rtp packet with following code:

```
Marshal.Copy(mixedChunk, 0, buf, buflen);
```

So how can I achieve with NAudio:

```
byte[] mixedChunk = MixChunks(rtpChunk, backChunk);
```

P.S: The sample Rate, Bits, Channel are equals for bought chunks:

```
8000, 16, 1
```

Thank you for help,
Piercarlo

Comment: Are your Arrays holding PCM samples in each of their slots? You need PCM samples and you also need to know both audio's SampleRate setting (for mixing at specific time of the other audio).

Comment: VC.One I know all of it !

Comment: If the parameters for all sources are similar it makes it a lot easier. It is probably wise to cast to a larger data type when mixing. Ideally cast to floating point first, then sum the streams. You _might get away_ with going to 64-bit signed int if you just need to sum without mixing

Comment: Don't forget to consult the [`[naudio]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/naudio?tab=Votes) tag, in particular you might want to browse questions related to [`MixingWaveProvider32`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bnaudio%5dMixingWaveProvider32&searchOn=3) and [`MixingWaveProvider`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnaudio%5DMixingWaveProvider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dears,
thanking for suggestions, I searched and I adapted some source code found on NAudio github repository to achieve my goal, so I post the solution that is working, may be will be usefull for some other else.

I premise that this code is handling only Raw Audio bytes, if you want to save the result on a ".wav" file you need to add the Header.

Method is the following:

```
public static byte[] MixBuffers(int count, params byte[][] bSources)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[count];
    int offset = 0;
    byte[] sourceBuffer = new byte[count];
    List<Stream> sources = new();
    foreach (var chunk in bSources)
        sources.Add(new MemoryStream(chunk));
    int outputSamples = 0;
    sourceBuffer = BufferHelpers.Ensure(sourceBuffer, count);
    lock (sources)
    {
        int index = sources.Count - 1;
        while (index >= 0)
        {
            var source = sources[index];
            int samplesRead = source.Read(sourceBuffer, 0, count);
            int outIndex = offset;
            for (int n = 0; n < samplesRead; n++)
                if (n >= outputSamples)
                    buffer[outIndex++] = sourceBuffer[n];
                else
                    buffer[outIndex++] += sourceBuffer[n];
            outputSamples = Math.Max(samplesRead, outputSamples);
            index--;
        }
    }
    foreach (var source in sources)
        source.Dispose();
    return buffer;
}
```